# Next.js styles not loaded on first page render

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an problem with my Next.js project. In both local development server and production build on the first render there is few seconnds with broken styles. It looks like styles are not loaded properly. After short time styles are properly applied.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share how you resolve this? Many thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

If styles is applied after a while it means everything works well but it is not enough optimised. FYI, in the browser the HTML elements are loaded before css [See How does css actually work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_works#how_does_css_actually_work).

This could be to many things, try to debug in your dev tools, in networks section to see how many times each elements takes before loading. The [waterfall view](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#record) could be handy.

To optimise your css, you could (non-exhaustive):

- Try using an CDN
- Try different [strategy](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#strategy) for loading scripts
- Try using a Platform as a Service that could optimise your final build (like Vercel, Heroku and many other)
- Spot any pains points (font or images too big)